# What is the Firebase Id Format called?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently creating an App with a firebase backend. When creating a new User it gets automatically assigned to an Id in an Format that looks like this: `v4xpr8hLrLR3W5VUTN2zZ3XXKrF3`.
Has this format a name? Like the `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` is called a Guid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UUID/GUID (RFC 4122) is a 128-bit number written as 32 hexadecimal characters.

A Firebase RTDB Push ID is 20 Base64 characters (a 120-bit number) and a Firebase user ID is (currently) 28 Base62 characters (a 166-bit number). This particular ID format doesn't appear to have an official name at the moment, as they are simply referred to as Push IDs and User UIDs.

However, inspired by the Firebase Push IDs, there is a new term that could be applied here: **ULID** - a *Universally **U**nique **L**exicographic Sortable **ID**entifier*. The Firebase implementation of these IDs is not compatible with the proposed [ULID spec](https://github.com/ulid/spec) (as the spec is Base32 and designed to be UUID compatible) but is similar enough that the name could be used here.